# Plotting a pie chart out of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, machine-learning, plot

I have a dictionary:

```
{'DATE': 65,
 'ORG': 93,
 'PERSON': 62,
 'GPE': 18,
 'PRODUCT': 18,
 'FAC': 4,
 'CARDINAL': 50,
 'ORDINAL': 15,
 'NORP': 10,
 'MONEY': 3,
 'PERCENT': 2,
 'TIME': 5,
 'LOC': 5,
 'QUANTITY': 2}
```

All I want is to get this plotted in a pie chart which shows the ***percentage distribution*** of these items. How can i plot this????

I have tried the solution here: [Trying to create a pie and bar chart from the data below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874023/trying-to-create-a-pie-and-bar-chart-from-the-data-below)

So i used the code which was published there as a solution:

```
amount_of_TP_ner_tags # this is the dictionary I want to plot. see above

# dont use values inside a list as column values for a dataframe
browser2 = {}
[browser2.update({key : val[0]}) for key, val in amount_of_TP_ner_tags.items()]

x = pd.Series(browser2)
y = pd.Series.sort_values(x)
z = pd.DataFrame(y)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8,4))
# you need to specify which column of the dataframe you want to plot (here 0)
z.plot(y=0, kind = 'pie', ax = axes[0])
z.plot(kind = 'bar', ax = axes[1])
axes[0].set_aspect("equal") # make aspect equal (such that circle is not eliptic)
#place the legend at a decent position
axes[0].legend(loc=1, bbox_to_anchor= (1,0.2), fontsize=11)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But I receive an error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-258-7ca72d2d0ca4> in <module>
      1 # dont use values inside a list as column values for a dataframe
      2 browser2 = {}
----> 3 [browser2.update({key : val[0]}) for key, val in amount_of_TP_ner_tags.items()]
      4 
      5 x = pd.Series(browser2)

<ipython-input-258-7ca72d2d0ca4> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 # dont use values inside a list as column values for a dataframe
      2 browser2 = {}
----> 3 [browser2.update({key : val[0]}) for key, val in amount_of_TP_ner_tags.items()]
      4 
      5 x = pd.Series(browser2)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

So how can I plot this?

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way is to use [matplotlib pie chart](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-pie-chart/)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

your_data = {'DATE': 65,
 'ORG': 93,
 'PERSON': 62,
 'GPE': 18,
 'PRODUCT': 18,
 'FAC': 4,
 'CARDINAL': 50,
 'ORDINAL': 15,
 'NORP': 10,
 'MONEY': 3,
 'PERCENT': 2,
 'TIME': 5,
 'LOC': 5,
 'QUANTITY': 2}

# Data to plot
labels = []
sizes = []

for x, y in your_data.items():
    labels.append(x)
    sizes.append(y)

# Plot
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Or simply `plt.pie(your_data.values(), labels=your_data.keys())`

Answer (score 12):

It's very easy

Step1: Extract the labels and values from the dictionary

```
# Get the Keys and store them in a list
labels = list(yourData.keys())

# Get the Values and store them in a list
values = list(yourData.values())
```

Step2: Simple Call the `matplotlib.pyplot`'s pie method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.pie(values, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

And you will be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

your_data = {'DATE': 65,
 'ORG': 93,
 'PERSON': 62,
 'GPE': 18,
 'PRODUCT': 18,
 'FAC': 4,
 'CARDINAL': 50,
 'ORDINAL': 15,
 'NORP': 10,
 'MONEY': 3,
 'PERCENT': 2,
 'TIME': 5,
 'LOC': 5,
 'QUANTITY': 2}

plt.pie([float(your_data[v]) for v in your_data], labels=[str(k) for k in your_data], autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not in plotting, you are trying to access the index of an integer.

try this:

```
browser2 = {}
[browser2.update({key : val}) for key, val in amount_of_TP_ner_tags.items()]
```